# C++ execute only member function or build entire object in new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I'm working on Virtual PLC module for EU07 simulator. This module will be responsible for simulating work of electric circuits that controls everything on locomotives (old, relay-based circuits). For maximum performance it would be better to have main loop of those vPLC's in own threads (separate for each loco). My question is what may be better approach: keep all vPLC's in one cointainer (vector?) and create threads inside for loop function, OR keep new threads in one cointainer (vector?) and build object in those new threads?
For communicating between rest of the application and those vPLC's i'm planning to use atomic vectors (I/O digital and analog).
Greatings, Greg:)

Comment: There is no perfect design. What's better depends on a lot of things; and the answer may change over time. Just try the both implementations and see what worked better for you.

Comment: Thanx for quick answer. So which way is easier in debuging?

Comment: I'd suggest preparing all data in the main thread and then use worker threads to perform calculations on that data. Then the main thread can wait for all workers to finish and compose the simulation results. Just be careful not to modify same data from multiple threads.

Comment: Every single "worker" have to run in constant loop (termination by reading atomic bool variable), scanning atomic "inputs" and setting atomic "outputs". Every single loco will have own sets of such inputs and outputs, plus non-atomic copies (keep working even if writing to atomics is not finished), so there should be no risk of modifing same data from different points. That's my plan.